# How to use terraform to store connection string from SQL Managed Instance in Azure Key vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am using terraform to deploy a SQL managed instance and need to store the 4 connection strings that come with it in azure key vault. According to terraform documentation for SQL managed instance:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_managed_instance
connection string is not an attribute that is exported, so can't just do an output and reference it. How would I identify these connection strings to store them in key vault?

If it is not possible with terraform I am open to powershell/arm solutions

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. Do you have any TF code to show which demonstrates your issue or what you want to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can store any secret in a key vault using terraform like so:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "the-secret-name"
  value        = "the-secret-value"
  key_vault_id = var.keyvault_id
}
```

Every connection string follows a certain syntax so I would put these together as strings based on the name, admin user and admin password, and add them to the key vault, similar to this:

```
locals {
    username = "admin"
    password = "abc"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_managed_instance" "example" {
  name                = "managedsqlinstance"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  
  administrator_login          = local.username
  administrator_login_password = local.password
  ...
}
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "sql-connectionstring"
  value        = "Server=tcp:${azurerm_mssql_managed_instance.example.name}.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=${local.username};Password=${local.password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  key_vault_id = var.keyvault_id
}
```

To find the connection strings and their exact syntax, you should have a look at the sql managed instance that has been created in the azure portal.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response. I was looking for a way to do it dynamically so terraform could grab the connection string from SQL MI, but it looks like SQL MI does not export connection string as a attribute (vs cosmos DB say, which does). Looking like Ill have to use powershell to fill in the remaining pieces